# What about sencha or Extjs?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch

i'm here to ask a general question about Extjs or any other web related technologies....

i found out that it is impossible to parse xml without the help of any webservice.....

so i would like to know about the pro's and cons about these kind of technologies specifically sencha.

whats the best feature you find intresting about this technology and also the worst thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJS, SmartClient, YUI, MooTools, etc are all rich Internet application (RIA) frameworks that allow you to integrate at the JavaScript and/or Google Web Toolkit levels.  I have generally seen ExtJS and SmartClient compared most frequently.  I have used SmartClient myself and one reason I did was because of the licensing differences between the two.

The biggest advantage of something like ExtJS or SmartClient is that they allow you to focus on building a data-driven service that easily integrates with their rich set of widgets.  This allows you to focus on your data and simply leverage their flexible, cross browser-ish, slick looking web GUI controls.

In my opinion, it's a great time saver and browser robustness advantage.  You can combine these with things like JQuery, etc.  In fact, you can use ExtJS and SmartClient together if you like. (although most people won't)

Answer (score 2):

There's a data package in ExtJS & Sencha Touch that allows you to easily bind client apps to JSON, YQL, XML datasources.

You should probably take a look at the documentation for the data.* part of the ExtJS library: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.XmlStore and this area is further improving in the forthcoming EXT JS 4